# Convert date String to number on Solaris shell script gives No such file or directory

Tags: shell, solaris

I have a date in the format "Thu Sep 22  3:50 2016", and I want to convert it to format:  "2016-09-22"

I tried the following shell script, which works fine for 'date', but gives error for user specified string: (I am working on Solaris platform). Any inputs will be helpful.

Input:

```
 #!/usr/bin/sh  
mydate="Thu Sep 22  3:50 2016"  
echo `date  +"%Y-%m-%d"`  
echo `$mydate  +"%Y-%m-%d"`
```

Output

```
./testShell.sh  
**2016-09-22**
```

./testShell.sh[6]: `Thu: not found **[No such file or directory]**`

Any pointers please?

Comment: What release of Solaris are you using? `cat /etc/release`

Comment: PS.'s now deleted answer was relying on GNU date` which isn't necessarily available on Solaris.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. Could yo please suggest then what could be the best possible way to convert "Thu Sep 22 3:50 2016" to  "2016-09-22"? May be I should also edit my question

Comment: It would help if you tell what Solaris version you use as I already asked.

Comment: I am sorry , I missed answering i earlier - it is :                               Oracle Solaris 11.1 X86
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
                           Assembled 19 September 2012

Answer (score 2):

Under Solaris 11, many `GNU` utilities are available under the `/usr/gnu/bin` directory so you just need to slightly modify your script to either use the full path the the GNU variant :

```
#!/bin/sh  
mydate="Thu Sep 22 3:50 2016"  
date  +"%Y-%m-%d"
/usr/gnu/bin/date -d "$mydate"  +"%Y-%m-%d"
```

or use the already existing symlink prefixed by `g` (for `GNU`):

```
gdate -d "$mydate"  +"%Y-%m-%d"
```

or set your `PATH` to look at `/usr/gnu/bin` first and keep your script unchanged.

```
PATH=/usr/gnu/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: On my Solaris 11.2 file server install, `gdate` is softlinked into `/usr/bin`, so no `PATH` environment variable update are needed.  I don't recall doing anything other than a normal install.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You are right, the `g*` symlinks are installed by default, answer updated to add this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this;

```
#!/bin/bash
mydate="Thu Sep 22  3:50 2016"  
date  +"%Y-%m-%d"
date -d "$mydate"  "+%Y-%m-%d"
```

Comment: This requires GNU `date`.