# Convert "Thu Sep 22 3:50 2016" to "2016-09-22" in Solaris, without GNU date

Tags: date, solaris

Could someone please suggest a simple and short approach to convert "Thu Sep 22 3:50 2016" to "2016-09-22" in Solaris, through a shell script?

I do not have GNU date available on Solaris as discussed in below post:
[Convert date String to number on Solaris shell script gives No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654352/convert-date-string-to-number-on-solaris-shell-script-gives-no-such-file-or-dire/39654920#39654920)

I need to query an sql server db, where date is saved in the format, "2016-09-06", hence I need to convert it

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you **do** have GNU date available but here is anyway one way to achieve this by scripting:

```
#!/bin/ksh
a="Thu Sep 22 3:50 2016"
echo $a | nawk '
BEGIN {
  m=1
  m2m["Jan"]=m++;
  m2m["Feb"]=m++;
  m2m["Mar"]=m++;
  m2m["Apr"]=m++;
  m2m["May"]=m++;
  m2m["Jun"]=m++;
  m2m["Jul"]=m++;
  m2m["Aug"]=m++;
  m2m["Sep"]=m++;
  m2m["Oct"]=m++;
  m2m["Nov"]=m++;
  m2m["Dec"]=m++;
}
{
  printf("%s-%02d-%02d\n",$5,m2m[$2],$3)
}'
```

output:

```
2016-09-22
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Oracle's sysdate?

select * from your_table where saved_date >= to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-MM-dd')

Comment: got the error:  'to_char' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: It's a PL/SQL statement. Can you update your original question to include the code you're running?

Comment: are you running MS SQL Server on Solaris??